# Surface integral first octant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to evaluate $$\iint_TxdS$$

Where $T$ is the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ which lies in the first octant $x,y,z\geq0$. So I used polar coordinates with $dS=rdrd\theta$ where $0\leq r\leq a$ and $0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2$. Hence

$$I= \frac{a^3}{3}$$

So my question is, is this correct? and is there any other way to solve this i.e spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Check your answer and I think something is wrong. The sphere in the first octant can be expressed as
$$ x=a\sin\phi\cos\theta,y=\sin\phi\sin\theta,z=a\cos\theta $$
where $\phi,\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$. Then
$$ dS=a^2\sin\phi d\phi d\theta$$
and hence
$$\iint_TxdS=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}a\sin\phi\cos\theta a^2\sin\phi d\phi d\theta=\frac{a^3\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: okey, looks like my approach was wrong. What I thought was possible, was that I could use the shade of the sphere as a circle in the $xy$ plane. Which is not a smart idea right?

Comment: Yes, you still can use, but the calculation is a bit long.

Comment: The calculation which I skipped was $\int^{\pi/2}_0\int^a_0r^2\cos\theta drd\theta$

Comment: Your $dS$ is wrong. You have to use $dS=\sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2}dxdy$, here $f=\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$.

Comment: thanks, I get it now. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome.